# twitter oauth trying to open authorization window in server side instead of client side

Tags: twitter, oauth

```
OAuthConsumer oauthConsumer = OAuthCons();
string t = oauthConsumer.getRequestToken();
string url = "";
if (t != null)
     url = oauthConsumer.OauthConfig.UserAuthorizationUrl + "?" + t;
context.Response.Write(url);
```

i have a twitter web app, and i want to ask for permissions to my clients, this is my twitter handler, i want to get the authorization url here and open this url in a new window in client side, but in server side this code tries to open a window in the server when this line runs "*oauthConsumer.getRequestToken()*", so iis tries to shellexec iexplore.exe. i dont want iexplore.exe processes in the server, i just want the url to send to the clients, why is this happening?